# Rebinding Function Name in Python

Tags: python, function, identifier

In Python 3, I tried the following code and the result is shown in comments:

```py
f = max
max = min
print(max(3,4))       # ① prints 3
print(f(3,4))         # ② prints 4
print(max == min)     # ③ prints True
print(max == f)       # ④ prints False
print(min == f)       # ④ prints False
```

I have the following questions:

1. I understand the result of ①. It prints `3` because the name `max`
   is now bound to what the build-in `min` function does. Is that
   right?
2. For result of ②, `f` still acts as a `max` even though the `max` is
   now actually a `min`. Is this because that the first line of binding
   `f = max` actually does not bind `f` to the name `max` but rather to
   the content of `max`? (Somewhat like pass by value as opposed to
   pass by reference)
3. For result of ④ and ⑤, why both of them are `False`? I thought at
   least one of them will be `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Correct, f is bound to the thing that `max` was bound to at the time you made the assignment.
3. `f` references the builtin `max` function, and `max` and `min` both reference the builtin `min` function.  Hence neither `max` nor `min` are the same as `f`.

```
>>> f = max
>>> max == f
True
>>> max = min
>>> max == f
False
```

Note that you can explore these same concepts much more easily with regular old ints:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = a
>>> a = 3
>>> a, b
(3, 2)
```

Comment: Sorry I still don't get question number 3. What exactly does `==` do? Does it compare reference or content?

Comment: `obj1 == obj2` is the same as `obj1.__eq__(obj2)`.  I believe function objects are compared by their `id` rather than the "content" of the functions.  But I think you're getting lost in the weeds here -- look at the second example with `a` and `b` which are regular old numbers.  Setting `a = 3` does not change the fact that `b` still points to `2`.  That's it, that's the whole thing.  `2 == 3` is `False` -- you don't need to get into the details of the implementation of `==` to understand why that's the case.  :)

Comment: Yes. I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With regard to (1) and (2), your understanding is correct.

With regard to (3), both `max` and `min` now reference the built-in function `min`, whereas `f` references the built-in function `max`. Therefore, both comparisons return `False`.

Comment: Does that mean the `=` works differently on functions and objects (I thought functions in Python are objects too)?
For object, `o2 = o1` simply gives another name to the object `o1` is pointing to. Both `o2` and `o1` points to the same object.
For function, `f = max` creates a new function object with the same content as `max` and assign it to `f`. So, rebinding `max` to `min` later does not affect `f`.
Is that right?

Comment: @LongYu you're describing the same behavior. `f = max` means that the name `f` points to the object (function) `max` points to. Then you have `max = min` that makes `max` point to a different object (function), so now `f == max` is `False`.

Comment: Get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`f = max` The name `f` is now bound to the maximum function

`max = min` The name `max` is now bound to the minimum function

Changing the value of `max` won't change the value of `f` so it is still bound to the maximum function therefore `max == min != f`

Answer (score 1):

Variables reference objects and keep no memory of where those objects may have come from. In your case, the variables reference function objects. The function objects themselves are anonymous. When you execute

```
f = max
```

`max` is referencing a function object. After assignment, `f` also references that same function object whose reference count is incremented by 1. You can now do anything you like to the variable `max`. The function object will have its reference count decremented by 1, but since its also referenced by `f`, it still hangs around.

Python, being the friendly language that it is, stamps that function object with its first reference when compiled. You can use that in a print statement to see the origins of the function object.

```
print('max', max)
f = max
print('f', f)
max = min
print('max', max)
print(max, max(3,4))       # ① prints 3
print(f, f(3,4))         # ② prints 4
print(f, max == min)     # ③ prints True
print(max, f, max == f)       # ④ prints False
print(min, f, min == f)       # ④ prints False
```

Results in

```
max <built-in function max>
f <built-in function max>
max <built-in function min>
<built-in function min> 3
<built-in function max> 4
<built-in function max> True
<built-in function min> <built-in function max> False
<built-in function min> <built-in function max> False
```